# Find position of element in jquery using .position() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing a simple animation by click a box to move to the right by 100px on each click. And I want that when its position reaches 400, it should move to the left by 100px on each click.

I did a `console.log()` but the console only show the initial positioning of the element, and it doesn't update after each click.
I also want the final position to show on the `<span id="info">` but it also doesn't update.

Why is that?

Many Thanks

jquery:

```
$('#somebox > a').click(function(e){
    var thisElem = $(this), 
        aPos = thisElem.position();

    thisElem.animate({ marginLeft: '+=100px' });

    if(aPos.left === 400){
        thisElem.animate({ marginLeft: '-=100px' });
    }

    console.log('finish pos: ' + aPos.left);

    $('#info').text(aPos.left + 'px');

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="somebox">
  <a href="#">show</a>
  <span id="info">10px</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#somebox{
  position: relative;
  background: #EEF0EB;
  border: 1px solid #dedbd7;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
#somebox a{
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #099;
  background: #0C9;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#info{
  display: block;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to make your life easier?

```
$('#somebox > a').click(function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    var rel = $this.data('rel') || '+=';

    var step = 100,  // amount to move each click
        min = 0,     // minimum left movement
        max = 400;   // maximum right movement


    $this.animate({ marginLeft: rel + step + 'px' },function(){
        var margin = parseInt($this.css('margin-left'),10);
        if (margin <= min || margin >= max){
            $this.data('rel',(rel == '+=' ? '-=' : '+='));
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T3JNB/)**

Comment: Note: I did use margin-left, but you can use the position left also.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually what I want is when the element reaches the end of its parent element, it should change to moving to the left. How do I do that? (I'm trying to make a carousel...)

Comment: @Shaoz: That is what it does (or as I understand it).[See the demo]. Unless you mean it resets to 0 and begins coming around again...

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your style sheet:

```
#somebox a {
 position: relative;
}
```

And on your jQuery where it says `marginLeft`, change it to just `left`. Do some more tweaking afterwards to get it to show the proper value.

Comment: This is right, you want to use the left, rather than the margin left, as it will report the position of the element, if you use margin, the position of the element will still be 0, just with the margin changed.

Comment: thanks for your response, actually my question was when it reaches the end of the parent element, the child element should start moving towards the left every 100px. How do I do that? (I'm trying to do a carousel. ;))